# W by H grid tiles?

Tags: python, grid

Imagine that we have a  `w`  by  `h`  grid, where the tiles are numbered starting at  `1`  in the top left corner.  `w`  (for width) and  `h`  (for height) have been stored in a function. You have access to these stored values, as long as you call them  `w` and  `h`. Write a program to return: The column number of a tile number given by the user. Start counting columns at column 1.

```
import subprocess
    def template(w, h, t):

        #w and h are memory locations that already contain values
        tile = t

        sum = ((t - 1) // w) + 1 
#END OF YOUR CODE

failed = 0
width = 1
while width <= 3:
    height = 1
    while height <= 3:
        tile = 1
        while tile  <=  width * height:
            result  =  template(width, height, tile)
            col = (tile - 1) % width + 1
            if (result == col):
                print "On a " + str(width) + " by " + str(height) +" board, with tile " + str(tile) +", col is " + str(col) + ", you got it RIGHT!"
            else:
                print "On a " + str(width) + " by " +:str(height)%+" board, with tile " + str(tile)%+", col is " + str(col) + ", you got: " + str(result)
                failed = 1
            tile += 1
        height += 1
    width += 1



if (failed == 0):
    print "Your code is CORRECT!"

    print "Please check your code, at least one test case did not pass."
```

I am almost there I think, but this formula isn't quite right and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: The instrsuction to store the width and height "in a function" is very odd as function usually are _not_ used to store values within themselves. Are you sure that's what it says?

Answer (score 0):

To create the grid, use a `list comprehension`.

```
grid=[list(range(x,x+w))for x in range(1,w*h,w)]
```

To find the column number of `t`, find the remainder of `t` divided by `w`:

```
t%w
```

So the function would be:

```
def template(w,h,t):
    grid=[list(range(x,x+w))for x in range(1,w*h,w)]
    return t%w
```

Example:

```
template(6,5,22)
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

See below pseudo code, this approach should work for you,

```
# divide t by h, the tile should reside in the next row
tileRow = (t/h)+1
# get the reminder of the division, that's the column number
tileColumn = t%h
```

see the sample code I tried below

```
>>> w = 5
>>> h = 10
>>> t =36
>>> tileRow = (t/h)+1
>>> tileRow
4     # the tile is in the 4th row
>>> tileColumn = t%h
>>> tileColumn
6     # the tile is in the 6th column
>>>
```

You may also have to check if the tile number is within in range, in the above example its w x h (50)

Please comment if you need anymore clarification. If this resolves your problem you may accept and vote the answer

Comment: I tried and still seem to be failing on some of them. It doesn't satisfy it for all columns and tiles.

Comment: Can we see some of your code please? So it will be easy for us to understand what you are trying to archive.

Comment: Kaveen, I updated the question to show the entire piece of code that I have.

Comment: @Orange I got a few questions. 1. Do you know the w and h? or do you have to find that out as well? 2. The tile number storing function, has it been provided to you? or do you have to code that as well?

This more sounds like a Chess board, where you name the squire with A1, B6 etc.